# Can I modify order number

Tags: orders

We have a customer move their servers to a new host and we had one days' data which got missed in between, while we have synchronized products and customers, new orders had already been taken and now the customer wants to find out if it would be possible to modify the order number to follow the old sequence.

I am aware of the table(eav_entity_store) that contains the last order id and the increment values which can avoid issues happening in future with order numbers, however we are trying to modify order numbers from the past.

Is there a list of tables, that I can update to achieve this result. I know modifying database directly is a very bad idea, but the for the customer it is a major issue as the orders integrate with their accounting system and it cannot take duplicates.

Comment: Yes obviously https://magecomp.com/magento-custom-order-number.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can, the tables you would want to have a look at are as follows:

- `sales_flat_order`,
- `sales_flat_order_item`,

These two tables basically contain all the information regarding an order, from address, delivery method etc. to products & qtys ordered.

You can relate them to each other as follows: the `entity_id` field in `sales_flat_order` is the `order_id` field in `sales_flat_order_item`.

The column named `increment_id` in `sales_flat_order` is the order number which is visible in the front- and back-end.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I shall try this and get back to you

Comment: You may also want to have a look at the `sales_flat_quote` table and check out which reserved order ids have been set there on active quotations.

Comment: And do a full database backup before messing with it!!!

Comment: Don't forget about the `..._grid` table(s).

Comment: @skv FYI, do read the above comments. I am just pinging you as other users haven't pinged you :)

Comment: I am so sorry, I did not get any notifications about this.  The suggestion actually worked foor us.